# How to redirect to page where request came from in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I currently work on a project an i want to redirect to page where request is came form, when request method is *GET*.

this is my views.py file
**Views.py**

```
def delete_patient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        patient_id = request.POST['patient_id']
        rem = Patient.objects.get(pk=patient_id)
        rem2 = CustomUser.objects.get(aid=patient_id, role=4)
        rem.delete()
        rem2.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'delete': 1})
    else:
        // //
```

so please tell me what I want to write in else part of view.

Comment: Typically for that, the server responds with a *405 method not allowed*. Especially since it is not even said that the request "comes from somewhere". For example one can make such request with `curl`, `wget`, etc.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So There is any solution available ?

Comment: what solution? You are violating the HTTP protocol by such redirection.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry i cannot understand, can you explain it, I am beginner in this things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically for that, the server responds with a *405 method not allowed*. Especially since it is not even said that the request "comes from somewhere". For example one can make such request with `curl`, `wget`, etc. You can work with a [**`@require_POST`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST) for example to return a 405 in case the method is something else than a POST (GET, PUT, PATCH, etc.):

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def delete_patient(request):
    patient_id = request.POST['patient_id']
    rem = Patient.objects.get(pk=patient_id)
    rem2 = CustomUser.objects.get(aid=patient_id, role=4)
    rem.delete()
    rem2.delete()
    return JsonResponse({'delete': 1})
```

If you really want to redirect to the referring page, you can try to access the `HTTP_REFERER` key from the [**`request.META`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) dictionary. But not all browsers per se send the referring page, and it is not even said that the request comes from a web client in the first place.

You thus can work with:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed, HttpResponseRedirect

def delete_patient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        patient_id = request.POST['patient_id']
        rem = Patient.objects.get(pk=patient_id)
        rem2 = CustomUser.objects.get(aid=patient_id, role=4)
        rem.delete()
        rem2.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'delete': 1})
    elif 'HTTP_REFERER' in request.META:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
    else:
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])
```

Comment: I think the key should be `HTTP_REFERER` (single R in referer), and not `HTTP_REFERRER`

Comment: @SindreBakkeØyen: yes, it is a typo in English, but was too late to fix, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer so unfortunately, easy to make a mistake. Thanks! updated.